# Aligning and positioning the node contents inside a table made of TikZ matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, positioning, alignment, tikz-matrix

I have difficulty aligning the contents of the nodes inside a TikZ matrix.

I'm specifically interested in achieving the kind of table below:

[image]

I got most of this code off the Internet and rearranged and added bits to it so it might have redundant parts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}%extbook
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black,font=\ttfamily\small},space/.style={minimum height=1.5em,matrix of nodes,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,column 1/.style={font=\ttfamily\small}},text depth=0.5ex,text height=2ex,nodes in empty cells]
  
\matrix (MYMAT) [matrix of nodes, ampersand replacement=\&, 
     row sep=-\pgflinewidth -1, column sep=-\pgflinewidth -1, % -1's are there to unthicken the inner borders
     nodes={text width=7.2mm,text height=1.2mm,font=\ttfamily\small,anchor=center,},% align=center,inner ysep=5pt didn't help at all
     column 1/.style={column sep=-\pgflinewidth + 8},
     column 2/.style={nodes={draw,very thick}},
     column 3/.style={nodes={draw,very thick}},]
{  1321 \& 2233 \& \\
   1322 \& 3111 \& \\
   1323 \& 4010 \& \\ };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to achieve the desired table appearance?

**UPDATE**
User `ignasi`'s answer solves the alignment problem substantially and produces a good enough table.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  
\matrix (MYMAT) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
     row sep=-\pgflinewidth -1 , column sep=-\pgflinewidth -1, 
     nodes={draw, very thick, minimum width=10mm, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=5.0mm, font=\ttfamily\small, anchor=center,},
     column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=20mm}},
     ]
{  1321 & 2233 & \\
   1322 & 3111 & \\
   1323 & 4010 & \\ };

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As such it's the accepted answer. However in an attempt to make the edges of the node narrow down a bit, by making the `minimum height=4mm` , the third column becomes:

[image]

Is there a way to further narrow down the node edges?

Comment: Since you accepted Ignasi's answer, it would be best to ask your updated question into another post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SebGlav yep the updated question might have been posted as a new post but it's more like an extension into the main problem rather than a basic problem itself. Let's call it "an exercise for perfection"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about differences between desired and achieved results, but a simplified version with `TiKZ` could be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}%extbook
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  
\matrix (MYMAT) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
     row sep=-\pgflinewidth, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
     nodes={draw, minimum width=10mm, inner sep=1mm, minimum height=5mm, font=\ttfamily\small, anchor=center,},
     column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=20mm}},
     ]
{  1321 & 2233 & \\
   1322 & 3111 & \\
   1323 & 4010 & \\ };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer. It solves the basic problem quite well.  I've just added an update to the question.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen the problem with your solution is due to a lower `minimum height`. Empty nodes in third column keep this value, but nodes on second need a larger height tobe large enough to write the inner text and they use a larger height.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen if you want to lower the inner margin, change `inner sep` parameter

Answer (score 2):

You should not have `minimum height` smaller from "font height + inner ysep". In the case that nodes content are only numbers (and not letters), you can use the following style for matrix nodes:

```
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
             nodes={draw, minimum width=10mm, inner sep=1pt, 
                    text height=1.2ex, % <---
                    font=\ttfamily\small, anchor=center},
             column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=20mm}},
            ]
```

In the case, that cells' contents contain letters b,d,j,g, than possible settings is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}%extbook
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
             column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
             row sep=-\pgflinewidth, 
             nodes={draw, minimum width=10mm, inner sep=2pt, % or 1pt
                    minimum height=2.4ex, 
                    font=\ttfamily\small, anchor=center},
             column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, minimum width=20mm}},
            ]
{  1321 & 2233 & bdjg\\
   1322 & 3111 & \\
   1323 & 4010 & \\ 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need tikz here? If not, this should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,14pt]{extbook}%extbook

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{1.5cm}|c|p{1cm}|}
        \cline{2-3}
        1321 & 2233 & \\
        \cline{2-3}
        1322 & 3111 & \\
        \cline{2-3}
        1323 & 4010 & \\
        \cline{2-3}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I draw some other graphs too using TikZ and I experience the same alignment problem in them, too so it would be best to draw this table using TikZ again because the information gained in solving the alignment problem would help the other drawings. That being said, this answer would better stay here because I may need to use the plain LaTeX tables somewhere in the document in the future and I haven't used the plain LaTex tables so far.